# Linux desktop with retro look

Tags: linux, user-interface, desktop-environment

I am looking for a Linux desktop which look retro, but is still fully functional in the inside.

Ideally I'd like a desktop which uses (or simulate) the 16-colours mode of the old PCs. The applications themselves need not to be in 16-colours, just the window and the menus. **I'd like something close to Windows 95, Windows 3.x or OS2/Warp in how it looks/feel and is used.**

This has nothing to do about memory efficiency, I actually think that strong, vivid colours look much better than the gray/black fad we have currently.

(I am not interested in neither LXDE nor XFCE, while those are not retro enough, among other reasons)

Comment: I'd like to know if my answer was relevant, or if it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can give a try at the [FVWM](http://fvwm.org/) window manager, it's fully customizable by a single configuration file, and it's [default theme](https://lwn.net/Articles/439478/) is something that looks like the old Windows 95 UI.

That can be a good start for what you want to use without too much work in the design.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, most Linux distributions should be able to be customised to the point you're after. My suggestion (whilst not taking into considerations regarding DE, required applications etc.) would be [Bodhi Linux](http://www.bodhilinux.com/).

Bodhi Linux uses the [Moksha Desktop](http://www.bodhilinux.com/moksha-desktop/), which has a number of [available themes](http://www.bodhilinux.com/softwaregroup/themes/) to meet your requirements (plus it is quite easy to engineer your own themes) - just [check out the user showcase here](http://www.bodhilinux.com/showcase/).

Comment: I admit I haven't tried the desktop yet, but looking at the screenshots, they do not look any retro at all. They look modern and feature creeped just like modern Gnome or KDE - although I could be wrong since those are just screenshots.

Comment: @Bregalad It's all about theming it yourself. There is 95/NT themes etc. and the ability to downscale it, just like Kubuntu themes :) best of luck mate.

Comment: So Im just tryging it right now and I really don-t like it. First, it doesn-t handle the kezboard correctlz, then I couldn-t start it from command line without using GDM, then it crashed the first time I ran it. It also have other issues I don-t like about other linux window managers, and is neither retro looking nor simple to use.

Comment: OK it was GDM who crashed not Moksha since it crashed again with another WM. I wonder why.

Comment: @Bregalad How did we go here?

Comment: @Bregalad ever solve this?